# Can we have multiple weather data from Worldweatheronline api?

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to get a weather information for one or more locations in a single api call ? Can this be possible in a http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx

http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=[APIKey]&q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5
This returns the result for the London city
but when I paas a data as comma seperated value like 
http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=[APIKey]&q=London,India&format=json&num_of_days=5

Then it is not providing the json for both London and India, nut provide the same json same as above link for London city only.

Can someone tell me the api call or is it possible to get the data for all the cities in a single call ?

Thanks

Comment: Send multiple requests?

Comment: Are you answering or asking ?

Comment: @ChrisBint I have total 20 records to get a weather so , should i need to go and call the  url 20 times ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that you can only have a single location defined in the request;

https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/docs/local-city-town-weather-api.aspx#qparameter

Based on this, you will need to submit a request for each location that you wish to check.

Comment: That is the parameter q right ? so If I send as London,India it will consider it as a London city and India as State correct ?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot chris I will try this and let you know and accept answer then